# Android relative layout center

Tags: android

In my relative layout I try to center 2 number pickers, the first number picker centers but the 2nd one only adds in after the first one, they dont both center equally. I think its missing something small but can't get it to work. below my code and a image showcasing the issue in red.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/test3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/purchaseCent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
        android:hint="@string/pin"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/test4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/test2"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:onClick="testMethod"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: two muppets]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a "spacer".
It will be 1dp wide (so to be completely trascurable) and completely transparent.
It must have an id, so that the NumberPickers can refer to it.

Put **this one** at the center.

The other two Views will be simply potitioned one at its left and one at its right side.

Solved.

Comment: Did exactly what you said, works 100%, thanks a million.

Comment: Well, experience matters, after all... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to "store" both `NumberPickers` into the same object (i.e. another `RelativeLayout` so you can place them side by side) and then center that however you need.

Comment: This solution involves the creation of a `nested layout`, which is bad for performances.

Comment: that's right, but it was just an example. Another object can be used for storing both `NumberPicker`s ;)

Comment: Still a suboptimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/test3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
        android:hint="@string/pin"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/test4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:onClick="testMethod"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_test" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```